# Precisely what is meant by "$\pi_1(M)$ is torsion"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading a paper where one of the conditions for a Theorem to hold is "the group $\pi_1(M)$ is torsion", where here $M$ is a compact differentiable manifold. What is meant by the first homotopy group of $M$ being "torsion"? Thanks.

Comment: A group is called *torsion*, if all its elements have finite order. For example any finitely generated abelian group can be written as a direct sum of its subgroup of torsion elements and a free abelian subgroup.

Comment: My 2¢: it's probably not a good idea to try and tackle differential geometry and homotopy groups without knowledge of basic group theory...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Just because someone hasn't heard the word "torsion" doesn't mean they don't have knowledge of quite a lot of group theory. For instance, I didn't encounter it (at least I didn't register it) until I was halfway through Hatcher's algebraic topology.

Comment: So how is this translated into a topological condition on M? i.e. for what sort of manifolds is the first homotopy group torsion?

Comment: @Tom The most common example is the real projective plane ($\Bbb Z_2$).

Comment: @Arthur. Thanks, but is there any more general geometric/topological interpretation associated to this condition, just as there is for the first homotopy group vanishing implying the manifold "has no holes"?